# Delay in getting SSE Events when configured via Azure Application gateway

Tags: python, server-sent-events, azure-application-gateway

We have implemented SSE Server in python. We are using EventSource to subscribe to the SSE server from Web angular project.

When the SSE Server is running in the local system, when an Event is pushed to the server, the event is getting pushed to the EventSource without much delay.

**Problem:** When the SSE Server is deployed to VM and configured via Azure Application gateway, when an Event is published to the server, there is a delay before the event is getting pushed to the EventSource. Sometimes, the delay is as  high as 15 seconds.

When the same SSE Server in VM is configured for direct access via ipaddress, any Event that is pushed to the server is getting pushed to the EventSource without much delay.

Is the delay in Events getting pushed to Event Source when access is configured via Azure Application gateway is happening because of the Azure app gateway? Any settings in the Azure Application gateway that needs to be configured specifically for SSE?

Python version: 3.8

SSE version: sse_starlette v1.3.4

Azure Application gateway Tier used: Standard

Browser: Chrome

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

@PramodValavala's solution works, but in my opinion there is a better solution, since the command disables buffering for all responses, even those where it might be useful.

Instead, you can simply set x-accel-buffering: no in the response header:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/#x-accel-buffering

The Application Gateway respects this header and does not buffer these responses.

Note, however, that NGINX does not forward this header to the application gateway by default. So if you are using an ingress controller or some other type of NGINX between your service and the application gateway, you should be aware of this. It is however possible to use the proxy_pass_header directive to instruct NGINX to forward this header. Simply add
`proxy_pass_header "X-Accel-Buffering";` to either the location or server context of the NGINX.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass_header

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to [response buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/proxy-buffers#response-buffer) which is enabled by default. So, your SSE response is first being buffered by Azure Application Gateway and once complete, is sent to the client.

Here is the command you can run to disable it using Azure CLI as mentioned in the docs for reference

```bash
az network application-gateway update --name <gw-name> --resource-group <rg-name> --set globalConfiguration.enableResponseBuffering=false
```